# How to select one object from the list of objects

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Html

```
 <form th:object="${klient}" th:action="@{/osoba}" method="post">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                <label >Imię</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control"  th:field="*{imie}" >
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                <label >Nazwisko</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{nazwisko}" >
                            </div>
                                <div class="select-list" id="selectlist">
                                    <select th:field="*{UserId}" >
                                        <option> -- </option>
                                        <option  th:each=" users : ${user}"
                                                 th:value="${users.UserId}"
                                                 th:utext="${users.lastName}"/>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
```

Cod

```
    @RequestMapping (value = "/osoba", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String dodaj (Klient klient){
    System.out.print(klient);
    return "redirect:/osoba";
}
@RequestMapping (value = "/dodaj" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String tworz (Model model){
    model.addAttribute("klient" , new Klient());

    List<User> lista = userService.getAllUser();
    model.addAttribute("user" , lista);

    return "dodaj";
}
```

I want to create a form in which he completes the fields for the client and assign an existing user to him.The problem is that I can't get the selected user id.

I get a message about the first select

> Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringSelectFieldTagProcessor

Comment: Can you show the whole error?

Comment: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringSelectFieldTagProcessor' (template: "dodaj" - line 178, col 49)

Comment: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'uzytkownik' of bean class [com.example.demo.Class.Klient]: Bean property 'uzytkownik' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Answer (score 0):

The error message shows that there is a problem with a property named `uzytkownik` , which I don't see anywhere in your template. Of course, you didn't include the complete template, so all I can say is that the problem is coming from somewhere else... apparently from line 178.

Comment: I changed the code a bit trying to fix the error.             org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'UserId' of bean class [com.example.demo.Class.Klient]: Bean property 'UserId' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?                                                                 the message is the same, I'm probably sending wrong but I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

Create the getter and setter methods for userId in Klient:

`public String getUserId()`

`public void setUserId(String userId)`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

in select I changed

```
<select   id="UserId" name="UserId" >
```

in controller

```
    @RequestMapping (value = "/osoba", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String dodaj (@ModelAttribute("UserId") Set<User> user, Klient klient){
   klient.setUsers(user);
    System.out.print(klient);

   klientServicee.createOrUpdateKlient(klient);
    return "redirect:/osoba";
}
```

it works but is it correct?